# Comandos para solucionar brillo estático y pantalla congelada tras suspender Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Tengo un problema desde que empecé a usar Ubuntu hace un año con Ubuntu 18.04 con la suspensión y brillo de mi portátil y aunque algunos amigos me dijeron que, con la actualización de 18.04 a 20.04, el problema se solucionaría, no sucedió en absoluto. Honestamente, no presté mucha atención a este problema hasta ahora, así que estoy un poco perdido en este tema. Mi pantalla se sigue congelando justo después de una suspensión, así que intenté implementar la hibernación en su lugar, complicando todo y sobre el tema del brillo, puedo mover la barra de regulación pero el brillo sigue siendo el mismo. Para ser honesto, no soy un experto en este sistema operativo. Solo estoy comenzando en este mundo por lo que sería de gran ayuda cualquier cosa que me pudieran sugerir para solucionar este problema.
Si es de alguna ayuda, a continuación se muestran las especificaciones de mi computadora portátil después de ejecutar el comando inx -Fxnzr. Muchas gracias.

Sistema:

Kernel: 5.4.0-47-genérico x86_64 bits: 64 compilador: gcc v: 9.3.0
Escritorio: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Máquina:

Tipo: Laptop Sistema: ASUSTeK producto: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X512DA_X512DA
v: 1.0 serial: 
Mobo: ASUSTeK modelo: X512DA v: 1.0 serial: 
UEFI: American Megatrends v: X512DA.305 Fecha: 16/07/2019

Batería:

ID-1: Carga BAT0: 18,4 Wh Condición: 32,5 / 37,1 Wh (88%)
modelo: ASUSTeK ASUS Estado de la batería: Cargando

UPC:

Topología: Modelo de cuatro núcleos: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U con Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
bits: 64 tipo: MT Arco MCP: Zen + rev: 1 caché L2: 2048 KiB
banderas: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
bogomips: 33535
Velocidad: 1342 MHz mín. / Máx .: 1400/2100 MHz Velocidades del núcleo (MHz): 1: 1397
2: 1397 3: 1222 4: 1222 5: 1397 6: 1397 7: 1222 8: 1222

Gráficos:

Dispositivo 1: Proveedor de AMD Picasso: Controlador ASUSTeK: N / A ID de bus: 03: 00.0
Pantalla: servidor x11: X.Org 1.20.8 controlador: ati, fbdev
descargado: configuración de modo, radeon, vesa resolución: 1920x1080 ~ 77Hz
OpenGL: renderizador: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 128 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
render directo: Sí

Audio:

Dispositivo 1: controlador de audio AMD Raven / Raven2 / Fenghuang HDMI / DP: snd_hda_intel
v: ID de bus del kernel: 03: 00.1
Dispositivo-2: AMD Raven / Raven2 / FireFlight / Renoir Controlador del procesador de audio: N / A
ID bus: 03: 00.5
Dispositivo-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio Proveedor: controlador ASUSTeK: snd_hda_intel
v: ID de bus del kernel: 03: 00.6
Servidor de sonido: ALSA v: k5.4.0-47-generic

Red:

Dispositivo-1: Adaptador de red inalámbrica Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac
Proveedor: controlador AzureWave: ath10k_pci v: ID de bus del kernel: 01: 00.0
SI: wlp1s0 estado: arriba mac:

Unidades:

Almacenamiento local: total: 238,47 GiB usados: 15,03 GiB (6,3%)
ID-1: / dev / nvme0n1 proveedor: Kingston modelo: RBUSNS8154P3256GJ3
tamaño: 238,47 GiB

Dividir:

ID-1: / tamaño: 87,69 GiB utilizado: 14,99 GiB (17,1%) fs: ext4
dev: / dev / nvme0n1p5

Sensores:

Temperaturas del sistema: CPU: 62,6 C mobo: N / A
Velocidades del ventilador (RPM): CPU: 2800

Por cierto, es un SO instalado en una partición junto con Windows 10.
Como resumen de mi problema:

Cuando voy a reiniciar y volver de la suspensión, se queda en una pantalla negra. Por otro lado el brillo no cambia hagas lo que hagas. Esos son los problemas

Comment: Hola! Te faltó indicar cuál es el problema con esos componentes / comportamientos. QUé debería hacer y no hace?

Comment: Cuando voy a reiniciar y volver de la suspensión, se queda en una pantalla negra. Por otro lado el brillo no cambia hagas lo que hagas. Esos son los problemas

Comment: Aunque la pregunta esta bien estructurada, tene en cuenta que puede que no encuentres una respuesta ya que este es un sitio sobre programacion y no sobre sistemas operativos en si. podrias llegar a probar en https://askubuntu.com/ (en ingles)

Comment: Es un problema viejo de Gnome (yo lo sufrí creo que en Ubuntu 12) y veo que [sigue pasando](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/power-suspendfail.html.en) cuando el hardware no es compatible. Si la suspensión no funciona, yo evitaría hibernar

Comment: A veces me pasa lo de la pantalla negra. Lo que hago es presionar Alt + F1 para cambiar a una TTY y luego Alt + F8 para volver a la pantalla de bloqueo, prueba a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Para ver más detalles del error, que te sale en `sudo dmesg` ?